# Why does my exterior door make a loud sound after I lock it?

Tags: wood, brick, door-frame, glass

I have a wooden back door with 9 glass panes and a wooden frame surrounded by brick inside and outside. Sometimes we have to push on it to get it to click all the way shut, if you know what I mean… but sometimes when I push on it to make shut all the way and even when I just shut it normally and don’t push on it because I’m not concerned with it being completely shut, as soon as it closes, about 0.5 seconds go by (almost immediately after) and it sounds like someone kicking the door from the outside and it scares me every dang time, especially at night when I’m double checking locks. It did it tonight.

I checked the lock, which was locked, then I pushed on it to make sure it was clicked shut, and when I let off from pushing “bang!”. What could this be from?

Comment: My guess is that the latch is slipping to a more outward ledge in the strike. Is there tension on the door as you try to close it, as though the hinges are binding? When it bangs, do you see or feel the door move in any particular direction? When you then _open_ the door, does the latch operate smoothly or does it catch? Please revise your post to address each of these questions.

Comment: When you said "all the way shut, if you know what i mean", you didn't mean [intentionally self-defeating the dead latch](https://youtu.be/4YYvBLAF4T8?t=550) did you?